# error C2511 : overloaded member function not found in Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums, overloading

This is the error im recieving.

```
Error   4   error C2511: 'Vector<T> Menus::sortListBy(sortType,Vector<T>)' 
: overloaded member function not found in 'Menus'   z:\documents\visual 
studio 2010\projects\oo_cw\oo_cw\menus.cpp  410 1   OO_CW
```

I believe this is something to do with me trying to use an enum that is included in a header but doesnt seem to be carried over to the other classes.

Here are the 2 headers involved and the function im struggling with::

Menus.cpp:

```
 Vector<connections> Menus::sortListBy(sortType sortKey,Vector<connections> sortList){}
```

Menus.h

```
#pragma once
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Airport.h"
class Journey;
#include <string>



typedef enum {BACK,FORWARD,INVALID,OPTIONS} result;
typedef enum {BOOK,VIEW,EXIT} firstChoice;


class Menus
{
public:
  Menus(void);
  ~Menus(void);
  firstChoice firstMenu();
  Airport bookingMenuFirst(Vector<Airport>);
  Airport bookingMenuSecond(Vector<connections>,Vector<Airport>);
  airlines bookingMenuThird(Airport,Airport,Journey&);
  string bookingMenuDate();
  bool showReciept(string,string,string,string,double,double,double);
  string showRecieptNames();
  void readReciept(string);
  void optionMenu(Journey);
  Vector<connections> sortListBy(sortType,Vector<connections>);
};
```

Journey.h

```
#pragma once
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Airport.h"
#include <string>
#include "Menus.h"

enum sortType {PRICE,TIME} ;

class Journey
{
 public:
  Journey(void);
  ~Journey(void);
//accessors
  Airport getStart();
  Airport getEnd();
  string getDate();
  airlines getAirline();
  string getStringAirline();
  double getTime();
  double getPrice();
  sortType getSort();
  //modifiers
  void setStart(Airport);
  void setEnd(Airport);
  void setPrice(double);
  void setTime(double);
  void setAirline(airlines);
  void setDate(string);
  void saveBooking();
  void setSort(sortType);


private:
  Airport startAirport;
  Airport endAirport;
  double price;
  double time;
  string date;
  airlines airline;
  Vector<string> splitBy(string,string);
  sortType sortingBy;

};
```

Menus.cpp header statements

```
#include "Menus.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Airport.h"
#include "Journey.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: Don't pass vectors by value.

Comment: the vector isnt causing me the problem i dont believe

Comment: Where are you calling the function? With what arguments?

Comment: Have you included the header where class's `Menus` definition is, in your `.cpp`?

Comment: im calling it in the same class (Menus.cpp)  currentQuery = sortListBy(newJourney.getSort(), currentQuery);

Comment: @40two yep, these are my header statements : #include "Menus.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "Airport.h"
#include "Journey.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;

Comment: In `Menus.cpp` at beginning of file did you `#include "Menus.hpp"`?

Comment: @40two just added me header calls to the post above

Comment: You have to post your `.cpp` as well at least as a link. To figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @40two just added a link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `enum sortType` is defined in `Journey.h`
- however, is not visible in `menu.h` and you are using `enum sortType` as input argument in the declaration of member function `Menus::sortListBy(sortType,Vector<connections>);` in the definition of the `Menus` class.
- In `Menus.h` remove the forward declaration of `class Journey;` and replace it with `#include "Journey.h"`.
- Remove `#include "Menus.h"` in `Journey.h`.
- There should be no problem, since you don't have circular dependency issues between `Journey` and `Menus`.

Comment: Amazing, worked a treat. This is my first c++ project so I'm still working my head around the whole header files and circular dependencies. I thought it may be a circular dependency error but wasnt sure how to resolve. Thanks a bunch.